# Responsive bar not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a site that includes a responsive navigation bar on mobile devices, but it doesn't work. When I click the button to show up the menu(burger), it does nothing. I made sure that all the files where in the same directory, checked the names, but nothing.

css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cuprum&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px ){

   nav {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
   min-height: 6vh;
   background-color: #000000;
   font-family: "Cuprum", sans-serif;
 }

  body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }

  .nav_links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height:100vh;
    top: 6vh;
    background-color: #000000;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 35%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }

  .nav_links li{
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .burger {
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

}

.nav-active{
  transform: translateX(0%) !important;
}
```

javascript:

```
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav_links");

  burger.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    nav.classlist.toggle("nav-active");
  })
}

navslide();
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: miss a dot here? `document.querySelector(".nav_links")` instead of `document.querySelector("nav_links")`

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: Can you provide a working example maybe into a jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e6wnfyuk/

Comment: Check your errors into the console log of the browser, nav.classlist is undefined

Comment: Please include the code in a Snippet in the question instead of (or in addition to) the fiddle. Questions here should be self contained and all code included in the question itself. External links are fine as long as the same code is included along side it here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change *("nav_links")* to *(".nav_links")*

- document.querySelector(".className");
- document.querySelector("#SomeId");
- document.querySelector("elementName");

try adding `.nav-active li {opacity: 1;}`

Here [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) you can read some information about querySelector()